# jquery (reverse) speed on toggled class (jsfiddle ex)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a quick question about jquery's toggle speed that I cannot implement in this particular case:

- I have two columns. A red one is hidden at first; the other (blue) takes up the entire width.
- Clicking the button: my code makes the first one shrink to two-third in order to make room for the second one which is one-third of the width.
- As you can see, the second (red) column appears with a smooth transition (1000ms). But the second click is an abrupt return to the initial state.

*My question:*

How could I implement in my code something  that would make the *second* click also go slower and not so abruptly?

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/farhang/Ljt5cg0L/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#side').hide()
}),
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $('#main').toggleClass('two-thirds');
    $("#side").toggle(1000);
});
```

Comment: You can try something like that: 

#main {background-color: blue; color: white; height: 100vh;transition: width ease-in-out 1000ms;}

Transition make changes smooth.

Chears :)

Comment: A make one update. U can use ease-in-out to get smooth in and out :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried it in the fiddle and sadly didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use .animate() or CSS3 Transitions, depending on your client base.

Jquery .animate()
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

CSS3 Transitions:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have used animate.css a lot but I had hoped - for the  sake of learning - that I could make that work within the function. I take it that it's not feasible?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Not in the way your thinking. So to kinda point you in the right direction let's look at what your current code does. When the document is loaded, you set the opacity of side to 0. This allows you to later call .toggle with a time span of the animation. Where as on the main div you simple remove or add the class as quickly as possible.

Comment: In order to adequately accomplish what your trying to do you need to leverage some type of timed animation for the main div as well as the side div any time you want the side div to be shown to the user. You could various JQUERY functions such as $.slideIn() $.slideOut() $.animate() or a couple others. You could also use CSS3 transitions.